# Derivation of a formula

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

The following is quoted from my book:

> A bar of length $l$, breadth $b$, and depth $d$ when loaded at the centre of a load $W$ sags by an amount given by:
> $$δ = \frac{Wl^{3}}{4bd^{3}Y}.$$

There is no derivation in my book regarding this formula. Can someone please derive the formula for me? I could not derive it. Please help.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Did you check the [wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory)?